# frequency table in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency

I have a continuous value `Tone`. How do I create a frequency table from the dataframe?

```
dataframe.Tone = [-0.9, -0.8, -0.6, -0.3, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]`
```

`resultDF`:

```
class interval | frequency 
(-1.0) - (-0.6) | 3
(-0.5) - (-0.1) | 2
   0   -  0.4   | 4
  0.5  -  0.9   | 1
   1   -  1.4   | 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `cut`

```
pd.cut(l,[-1,-0.6,-0.1,0.4,0.9,1.4]).value_counts()
(-1.0, -0.6]    3
(-0.6, -0.1]    2
(-0.1, 0.4]     4
(0.4, 0.9]      1
(0.9, 1.4]      3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: how to automatically change the class interval range? without defining [-1,-0.6,-0.1,0.4,0.9,1.4]. range = 0.4

Comment: @Ruzannah the second param of cut can be an `int` which is the number of bins you want

Comment: @Ruzannah something like `pd.cut(l,np.arange(-1,1.4+0.5,0.4)).value_counts()
`

Comment: how about `float` ?

Comment: @Ruzannah what you mean float ?

Comment: i want to set bins as `float: 0.4`

Comment: @Ruzannah did you run this `np.arange(-1,1.4+0.5,0.4)`?

Comment: what `1.4+0.5` param meant?

Comment: @Ruzannah adding one step size , you should look at this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html